# Online, is there any equivalent to the Japanese web slang of ending a sentence with "w" or in English using "lol" just to indicate good-nature/humor?

Tags: slang, internet-slang

I was wondering because while I am decent at speaking Chinese, I've just recently started sending messages online using it (16 years late lol). I've ended *one* sentence with "笑" but even that was borrowed from my Japanese interactions and not Chinese. I've also ended a few with "w" like in Japanese, but that just feels weird and (rightfully) out of place. Is there any ending that's more common so I can become more undercover on Chinese language twitter? Thanks!

Comment: maybe just :) but it's not language specific.

Comment: Using `wwwww` is hard to see. But you can see someone using [`草（日本语）`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E8%8D%89%EF%BC%88%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AF%AD%EF%BC%89%22).

Answer (score 4):

The best i can think of is **233**.

> It is originated from Chinese popular forum side [猫扑](https://www.mop.com), the 233 is the number of emoji. Then it started to get viral to other forum side, people often lengthen the `3` behind the `233`. The longer the `3`, the funnier it gets to.

No.233 emoji is a dog having the face expression of >_< , see below picture:

[image: 233 emoji of www.mop.com]

You would have something like this:

`233333333333333333333333333333333`

Answer (score 4):

As [one of the other answers](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/37148/15684) stated, 2333 = hahaha.
Also, xswl (short for 笑死我了) = laugh to death

Answer (score 4):

1 笑

2 `ヾ(≧▽≦*)o` or similars

3 haha

4 XD

5 :)

6 23333

7 草 (Yeah, some Japanese lover also use it, but be careful, other people use it as 'fuck')

8 lol

9 wwwwww

10 哈哈

[image]

**Chinese use stickers(表情包) more to express these emotions.**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn more about these stuff, you could try going to the chinese "youtube" website which is https://www.bilibili.com/ and probably find something funny to watch. 
The 弹幕 which are the instant comments from other users may show a lot of other web slangs.